# Are questions requesting help with "Fake Virus" code acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions

Just wondering if questions requesting help with Fake Viruses are considered acceptable?

If the answer is no, what would the correct course of action be if someone asks a question that involves the creation of help with code used for a Fake / Joke virus?

Comment: @RyanM that's kind of the point is a "Fake" virus malicious? I think so, but trying to gage the communities opinion.

Comment: It's irrelevant if it's malicious or not.

Comment: What constitutes a "Fake Virus" for you? I've often enough seen code that would by itself not be harmful, but the question implied the real code contained the other bits.

Comment: An example would be a fake virus that simulates Petya, but doesn't harm the computer it's meant to be a joke. That to me still seems malicious.

Comment: I did make a point of searching but didn't find anything, this duplicate does appear to answer my question. Might be worth leaving as it mentions "Fake Virus" specifically, which when I searched I found nothing.

Comment: simply downvote it, it is as far as i know not offtopic, and so your only way is to "dislike it"